# Microsoft Azure AKS Locations (command line strings)

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am working through my AKS tutorials and haven't been able to find a comprehensive list of Azure AKS locations in command line form.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-group-create) is sparse, and the examples usually give only one or two locations: eg. `eastus` and `westus`.

`az group create -l westus -n MyResourceGroup`

Can anyone point me to the official list of AKS locations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this answer myself based on @CharlesXu 's comment so it can be officially accepted because I think green checkmarks are helpful to others when searching...

In short, to use the display name for Locations when issuing commands:

`az group create -n groupName -l 'East US'`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of service locations:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/container-service-quotas

Comment: Yes, I saw that documentation page. It wasn't as helpful as I hoped it would be. I am asking for the actual strings to use when using the command line. For example: `eastus` and `westus` instead of  **West US** and **East US**

Comment: Yep, I understand. I cannot find a CLI method for listing the available AKS regions. Let me do some extended research and will file an Azure CLI issue if needed.

For translating region Display names to short name, the `az account list-locations` command can be used.

Comment: @user1873858 Do you try the command like `az group create -n groupName -l 'East US'`? The location in the document can be used like that.

Comment: Charles, your response comes closest. If you change your comment to an answer I will accept.